# Unable to set value of AccordionItem.IsSelected

Tags: wpf, accordion, wpftoolkit, expander

Is there any way to set a WPF accordion so all it's items are collapsed by default, only when I click the expander button it should expand?

**Update**
According to the template I realized that what selects the item is the `IsSelected` property of the `AccordionItem`, the problem is, when I try to set this property (from code in a button click handler) I get the following `InvalidOperationException`:

```
Cannot modify the IsSelected property while item is locked.
```

StackTrace:

```
  at System.Windows.Controls.AccordionItem.OnIsSelectedPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) in C:\dd\WPF_1\src\wpf\src\ControlsPack\WPFToolkit\Layout\Accordion\System\Windows\Controls\AccordionItem.cs:line 315
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at System.Windows.Controls.AccordionItem.set_IsSelected(Boolean value) in C:\dd\WPF_1\src\wpf\src\ControlsPack\WPFToolkit\Layout\Accordion\System\Windows\Controls\AccordionItem.cs:line 284
   at WpfSampleApplication.MainWindow.btn_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in d:\users\shimmy\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WpfSampleApplication\MainWindow.xaml.vb:line 9
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at WpfSampleApplication.Application.Main() in d:\users\shimmy\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WpfSampleApplication\obj\x86\Debug\Application.g.vb:line 64
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control which item is selected with the `SelectedIndex` and `SelectedItem` properties of the `Accordion` control itself.

You can put a non-visible `AccordionItem` as the first item to show all items initially as collapsed:

```
<toolkit:AccordionItem Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

To open a particular item, set the `SelectedIndex` property in the `Loaded` handler.  Or you can do all in XAML if you are using behaviors:

```
<toolkit:Accordion>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="SelectedIndex" Value="2"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

**Edit:**

The "xmlns:i" namespace refers to `System.Windows.Interactivity` which is part of WPF4.  The "xmlns:ei" namespace refers to `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions` which is part of the:

- [Microsoft Expression Blend Software Development Kit (SDK) for .NET 4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=75e13d71-7c53-4382-9592-6c07c6a00207&displaylang=en)

After you have added the references to your project you can use this to set up the namespaces:

```
<Window ...
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
    ...>
```

Comment: Can you please include the `i` and the `ei` reference? it shounds amazing to me! finally getting rid of verbose blah blah Storyboards!

Comment: Is the Exp. blend kit included if Microsoft exp. studio is installed?

Comment: Yes, and in that case you can find and the assembly reference just by searching for "Expression".  Or if you open the project in Blend and add any "Behaviors" (under "Assets"), Blend will add the namespaces and references automatically.

Comment: when you comment, please include the @Name reference, so I get notified for a new comment.
I wish I could upvote more than once, well done Rick! You just randomly helped me find a solution to something I am looking to implement long time ago (the EventTrigger class's contructor is internal and thus cannot be inheritted)! Thank you!!!